# Error configuring File Share Witness in a Windows 2012R2 Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, high-availability, windows-cluster, alwayson

I'm learning how to configure a simple W2012R2 Cluster for a AlwaysOn Basic Availability Group. I have this VM scenario:
 - 1 DC (outside the cluster)
 - 2 SQL Server Standard 2016 (in a Cluster)

I've created a File Share in the DC to set it as File Share Witness (FSW). When trying to configure the witness, I get the following error:

There was an error configuring the file share witness '\testbagdc\fsw'.

Unable to save property changes for 'File Share Witness'.

The system cannot find the file specified

If I get inside the share, I can see a guid-named folder with nothing inside. I've also granted full control over the cluster computer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by giving the cluster account full permissions to the witness folder.

More info here:
http://www.dbaglobe.com/2014/07/fix-issue-when-configuring-file-share.html

Answer (score 0):

After several tries without success, I've tried again but this time creating the network share in the same wizard and now it magically worked.